# First cohomology of topological spaces with non abelian coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I would like to have a reference about the construction and properties of $H^1(X;G)$ for $X$ a topological space and $G$ a non-abelian group (in the spirit of expanding and clarifying the first rows of the first comment to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226123/non-abelian-simplicial-cohomology)).

Connections of that with the theory developed in Hatcher's AT Section 4.3, i.e. correspondences between $H^1(X;G)$ and maps $\langle X,K(G,1)\rangle$ (which in his treatment involves only abelian groups) are also very welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The book [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html)  deals even with coefficients in a crossed module and uses techniques in the book to calculate some homotopy classes of maps: see Section 12.3.

The background is that to get some nonabelian coefficients it is desirable to have some nonabelian type of chains, and a first candidate seems to be  crossed complexes.

Let me know of any further questions on this.